# a video with .m4v format does not star downloading in my web while its in the root

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have been adding a video file named `Video.m4v` to the root of my web site. when I type `www.forexample.com/Video.m4v` it confront `404 error`
 While I expect a notification for starting to download this. what exactly should I do to make this happened? I want when I type `www.forexample.com/Video.m4v` in browser it starts to download the video . 
Appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: What is your web-server? Does the server know how to handle an _*.m4v_ file?

Comment: @Alexander I am not sure, I did not add any codes to it. I expect that it should treat like images or pdfs . so you mean I should do some changes in web.config? how about mp4 files?

Comment: Try to [add MIME-types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) of above mentioned extensions to the site configuration.

Comment: thank you very much , I tried MP4 and it seems its fine. but I will check your help and I will inform you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) says:

> IIS 7 will not return file types that are not added to the `<staticContent>` element or that have mappings in the `<handlers>` element by default. This behavior prevents unauthorized access to files that do not have mappings in the IIS 7 configuration settings.

So, you need to define MIME-type for specified file extension in the application, site or server configuration using `<mimeMap>` element. You could also use **MIME Types** feature of IIS Manager instead of editing configuration file directly.

To instruct browsers to download any static content use [`download`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute for hyperlink.